# Refreshing a listview

Tags: android, listview, view, refresh, listadapter

I have a listview that's populated by rows that get their data from a web server. It all works totally fine except I want to have a refresh button to re-download the data. I'm getting the data through an asynctask (getting the data in doinbackground) and then setting the listadapter in onpostexecute. All I do to run the asynctask which should take care of everything is run

> new PopulateListTask().execute();

However, in my optionsSelect method, creating a new asynctask just like I did in oncreate doesn't do anything. It doesn't even enter doInBackground. I've tried using listView.invalidate() and listView.invalidateViews(). Is there some special way I'm supposed to repopulate a listview?

My only guess is that since I'm using a custom adapter, my getView method is creating some kind of error, but that wouldn't explain why it's not even entering my asynctask's doInBackground method. Thoughts?

Edit: Posting some code. This is a trimmed down version.

`

```
 private class PopulateListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Quote>>{

 @Override
 protected ArrayList<Quote> doInBackground(Void... params) {

quotes = Helper.getQuotes();

return quotes;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Quote> quotes){

setListAdapter(new QuoteAdapter(ctx,R.layout.quote_row,quotes));

}


}

private class QuoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Quote>{

    ArrayList<Quote> items;
    int resource;

    public QuoteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Quote> items){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);

 this.items = items;
 this.resource = textViewResourceId;




    }

    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

      View v = convertView;

       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(resource,null);

        // do stuff with v

       return v;
 }



}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case(MENU_REFRESH):
        new PopulateListTask().execute();


 }
```

`

Ok hopefully this works, sorry I'm still not totally sure the best way to enter code.

Edit2:

I'm getting this in my logcat when executing my asynctask the 2nd time. Any idea what it means? I tried googling to no avail.

> W/InputManagerService(   52): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43b9dee8

Comment: Post the code for your custom adapter, the task and the onClick of the refresh button.

Comment: Put in some code. I've been told to call notifydatasetchanged and notifydatanull or whatever the other method is. But I'm not really adding to an array and then repopulating, I want to totally destroy the listview and redo it from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in creating my options subMenu. I had

> menu.addSubMenu( MENU_REFRESH, 0, 0, "Refresh");

isntead of

> menu.addSubMenu(0, MENU_REFRESH, 0, "Refresh");